# How to get parser error as exception in docutils

Tags: python, docutils

I have the following simple piece of code to parse a reSt file and return the corresponding DOM tree.

```
from docutils import nodes, utils
from docutils.parsers import rst

def _rst_to_dom(self, txt):
    """Parse reStructuredText and return corresponding DOM tree."""

    document = utils.new_document("Doc")
    document.settings.tab_width = 4
    document.settings.pep_references = 1
    document.settings.rfc_references = 1
    document.settings.raw_enabled = True
    document.settings.file_insertion_enabled = True

    rst.Parser().parse(txt, document)

    return document.asdom()
```

This works great, but when the parser finds some problem with the input, instead of raising an exception so that my program knows that there is something wrong, it simply prints out an error message to the standard output and returns a tree with what it could do. How can I get it to raise an exception? Or, how can I know that something was amiss?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Set the [halt-level](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/user/config.html#halt-level):

```
from docutils import frontend, nodes, utils
from docutils.parsers import rst

def _rst_to_dom(txt):
    """Parse reStructuredText and return corresponding DOM tree."""

    settings = frontend.get_default_settings(rst.Parser)
    settings.halt_level = 2  # 1 info 2 warning 3 error 4 severe 5 none
    document = utils.new_document("Doc", settings)

    rst.Parser().parse(txt, document)

    return document.asdom()

print(_rst_to_dom('*holla die Waldfee'))
```